# Replenish "from zero"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word to express that the stock of a product was replenished *and* it was previously *completely out of stock*. Something like "replenish the stock from exactly 0 to > 0".

As far as I understand, *replenish* and *restock* don't express anything about the previous state, both simply says that stock was added, regardless of the previous stock level.

My preference is to find a single word.

Comment: It is difficult to find an unambiguous single word, probably there isn't in common usage. The usage of the common verbs like _replenish_ and _restock_ would make sense in the context, with additional wording. A nonce word (or a neologism) like _dezero_ or _unzero_ could work if you really need a single unambiguous verb; however, they are not defined in any dictionaries. Additionally, _OED_ lists the verbs _rezero_ and _zeroize_ for the meaning 'to reset to zero' as an opposite of what you want (although used in calibration/measuring context).

Comment: Finding a single word is not a "must" for me. "refill" is easy to grasp and is also universally understood even among non-native speakers, which is an advantage in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe ***refill***:

> If you *refill* something, you fill it again ***after it has been emptied.***
>
> > I ***refilled*** our glasses.
>
> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/refill))

It is used for stocks as well.

> From this summer retailers will be allowed to ***refill*** cash machines from the notes in their tills, rather than waiting for a fresh delivery of banknotes. (*Times, Sunday Times 2013*).

There is also ***fill again***:

> fill something that had previously been emptied
>
> ([FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fill+again))

Comment: I have to disagree. In practice, we refill (or "fill again") things that aren't empty. Examples: "[Ok to refill a propane tank that's only half empty?](https://www.rv.net/forum/index.cfm/fuseaction/thread/tid/25449917/print/true.cfm)" and "[You can always PARTIALLY drain the pool and refill it with clean water](https://www.mrpoolman.com.au/blogs/news/i-give-up-should-i-just-drain-my-pool)"

Comment: Yes, it is true in practice. When you say refill, people will not necessarily think that the stock was previously completely empty, without looking at what some dictionaries say. Doubt however that there is something more specific.